# How to set default form Value from Observable?

Tags: angular, typescript, observable, angular-reactive-forms

**Here is my ts component**

```
export interface Product{
    id?:string,
    name:string,
    price:string;
    quantity:string;
    tags:Tags[];
    description:string;
    files: File[];
}

product$:Observable<Product | undefined>;

ngOnInit(): void { 
  this.store.dispatch(new productActions.LoadProduct(fromProduct.getCurrentProductId.toString()));
  this.product$ = this.store.pipe(select(fromProduct.getCurrentProduct));
}
```

Last and the second statements gather the value of product observable and work fine.

```
this.product = this.fb.group({
    name:['',[
      Validators.required,
      Validators.minLength(1),
      Validators.maxLength(128)
    ]],
    price:['',
    Validators.required],
    tags:this.fb.array(this.tags),
    quantity:['',Validators.required],
    description:['',
    Validators.required]
  });
}
```

**Now what I want is to set the default value of Form from Product$ (observable)**

The above code sets the default value of name ''. But I want to set a default value from (product$ | async).name----->> this works fine in Html, but I have no idea how to do it in typescript.

Thanks for helping me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could put your whole FormGroup initialization into a subscribe.
Don't forget to use the first operator though, since you only want to do this once and then unsubscribe.

```
this.product$
    .pipe(first())
    .subscribe(product => {
        this.product = this.fb.group({
            name:[product.name,[
              Validators.required,
              Validators.minLength(1),
              Validators.maxLength(128)
            ]],
            price:['',
            Validators.required],
            tags:this.fb.array(this.tags),
            quantity:['',Validators.required],
            description:['',
            Validators.required]
          });
        }
    });
```

Comment: Is there a way to do this without `subscribe`?

Comment: @trebor Sure, you could transform the `product$` observable to a promise with `firstValueFrom` and then use await.

Answer (score 3):

You need to subscribe to the observable so that when there is a value passed, you are able to receive it and do something using it. Probably something like this:

```
this.product$ = this.store.pipe(select(fromProduct.getCurrentProduct));
this.product$.subscribe(valueFromSubscription => this.product.patchValue(...));
```